# Where can i get wpcom-carousel?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I am looking for a good carousel, I loved the one at http://icanhascheezburger.com/ and http://tylertalent.com/photos/
I looked at the code and it seems its called wpcom-carousel, but I dont know which plugin on my wordpress installation would give me the same carousel.

Comment: if you didn't find any plugin, chances are real that there *is* no plugin. but you don't need a plugin for such a carrousel, you can manually implement it in your theme...

Comment: How can it be implemented manually in my site? Just include javascript file and classname to my pictures? I searched a bit more and found that its made by wordpress.com and is available on all of their blogs. I want to know if it is possible to include it in my own installation.

Answer (score 1):

If it is definitely a WordPress.com Plugin then you might want to sign-up for a free WP.com account and have a play with the Plugin.

If you view page source on your WP.com site then you should see what JS libraries it is using, then try to use the same ones in your own Plugin.